# Exotic mongoose query about an array

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I'm having trouble with a query in mongoose, and I'm looking for your advice:

I need to retrieve some elements from a collection, if an element is in an array. Hard to explain, here's the deal: I need to get the message if the current user is among the recipients

```
var Message = new Schema({
    recipients: [{
        pseudo: {type: String},
        slug: {type: String, index: true}
    }],
    sender: {
        pseudo: {type: String},
        slug: {type: String, index: true}
    },
    content: String,
    dateCreated: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    readBy: [{
        pseudo: String,
        slug: String,
        date: Date
    }]
});
```

In the same way, when checking for unread messages, I need to retrieve some messages if my user is NOT in the readBy array.

I know how to use the $in operator, but it works the other way around. Is it possible to achieve this kind of query?

EDIT: I found out about the $elemMatch operator, and it will do fine with my first probleme, but I'm not sure how to use it for the unread messages. Is it possible to add a NOT clause in there?

Comment: You can use the [`$not`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/#_S_not) operator for that.

Comment: yeah, indeed it works, $not followed by $elemMatch ! Thank you !